# Is there a stricter version of .Single()?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there a stricter version of .Single() such that an exception is thrown if more than one comes back from said query?  I can always create an extension method, but wondered if I was reinventing something that already exists.

Comment: It does. .First() is the version that does not do this check.

Comment: That's precisely what `Single` does (it's actually the only difference with `First`)

Comment: Single() should do exactly that, if it doesn't it's a bug in whatever linq implementation you are using (which is not that unlikely). There is a First() function which should not throw an exception when there is more the one result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) already throws an `InvalidOperationException` if the result contains more than one element (or if it is empty). You were probably confusing it with [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx), which *doesn't* throw if there is more than one element.

Comment: If you were looking for a method that throws *if and only if* there is more than one element, but will still work if the result is empty, use [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx).

Comment: thanks for that comment + ty all who answered.  I'm not sure that the question was worth 7 downvotes.  Such is SO sometimes.  ;-)  .SingleOrDefault() & .Single() are perfect as is then.

Answer (score 5):

That's exactly what `Single` does.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`Single()` already throws a InvalidOperationException in this case.

Incidentally, this means that behind the scenes it runs enough code to try to obtain at least two elements - so it can throw if it succeeds, this means `First()` is more performant if you either know that there is only one such item, or don't care. Choosing `First()` in a case where `Single` is another possibility sits somewhere between being the only sane approach and a dangerous optimisation, depending on circumstance.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx):

> Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if
>   there is not exactly one element in the sequence.

I think you are confusing `Single` and `First`, which behaves the way you describe.